# Difference calculate between two data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Reading the input and output file

```
Input2 = pd.read_excel('~.xlsx')
input = pd.read_excel('~.xlsx')
```

Checking for the columns which are different from the input and output file

```
inserted_cols = input2

cols = ([col for col in inserted_cols if col not in input ]
            +  [col for col in inserted_cols if col in input ])

input = input2 [cols]
```

Input:-

```
ram     redist  rotril  shyam
asdasd  asdasd  fff     rtrr
adsd    adsd    zzz     fhgfhgf
sadasd  sadasd  bbb     cbcbv
zxcxz   zxcxz   xxx     hjhj
fdfsd   fdfsd   rrr     piio
```

Input2:-

```
ram    shyam    tramp   rotril
asdasd  rtrr    asdasd  rtrr
adsd    fhgfhgf adsd    fhgfhgf
sadasd  cbcbv   sadasd  cbcbv
zxcxz   hjhj    zxcxz   hjhj
fdfsd   piio    fdfsd   piio
```

Output i am getting:-

```
ram    shyam    tramp   rotril
asdasd  rtrr    asdasd  rtrr
adsd    fhgfhgf adsd    fhgfhgf
sadasd  cbcbv   sadasd  cbcbv
zxcxz   hjhj    zxcxz   hjhj
fdfsd   piio    fdfsd   piio
```

Expected Output:-

```
ram     shyam   tramp   rotril
asdasd  rtrr    NA      fff
adsd    fhgfhgf NA      zzz
sadasd  cbcbv   NA      bbb
zxcxz   hjhj    NA      xxx
fdfsd   piio    NA      rrr
```

Can help what i am doing wrong in my code?

Comment: Please include the input, output, and expected output as text in the question.

Comment: Have made the changes....Kindly have a look

Comment: not sure I follow. Do you have two inputs, and one of them is called 'output'? you seem to be reading some file called 'output' at the very beginning of the process. Is that input or output?

Comment: i have modified the names of my code for better understanding. Basically i have two input file named input and input2 and i want to order the input file based on the column order of input2 and if any column is present in input2 and not in input it should be there in thr final output with only the column name and blank value

Comment: You still have "inserted_cols = output" in the second block of code. I think you should fix that one too.

Comment: Another question - to mix data from the two dataframes you'll have to somehow join them. How do you match rows from input1 to rows from input2? By their order? something else?

Comment: can you help me how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
input1.index.name = "inx"
input2.index.name = "inx"

new_cols = list(set(input2.columns) - set(input1.columns))

input1 = input1.join(input2[new_cols])

res = input1[input2.columns]
print(res)
```

The output is:

```
        ram    shyam   tramp rotril
inx                                
0    asdasd     rtrr  asdasd    fff
1      adsd  fhgfhgf    adsd    zzz
2    sadasd    cbcbv  sadasd    bbb
3     zxcxz     hjhj   zxcxz    xxx
4     fdfsd     piio   fdfsd    rrr
```

Comment: Thats great...thanks roy...can we make the column tramp empty..i want only the column name with rows blank

Comment: or can i color this difference column i.e. column 'tramp' to differentiate from the other columns